# How can I read multiple files from hdfs using java?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have been playing around with Hadoop and right now I am trying to figure out a way  to read multiple files from a directory. The code below works fine when I read a file. What would be the best way to read multiple files from hdfs and read each line form every file.

```
try {
        Path pt = new Path("hdfs://profile/generate/work/output/errors.txt");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(job.getConfiguration());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
        String line;
        line=br.readLine();
        while (line !=null){
            //sendemail
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You could have a great win in performance by having a thread that does the reading. Doing so you could spawn a thread for each file, hence reading multiple files at once.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path(path)) and make a for on your status before read one hdfs file

> FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(new Path("path"));

```
for (int i=0;i<status.length;i++){

        //afficher le contenu d'un fichier hdfs
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(status[i].getPath())));
        String line;
        line=br.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            System.out.println(line);
            line=br.readLine();
        }
    }
```